# Python Pandas, Matplotlib: Plot multi-index DataFrame possible?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my `df`:

```
                   User  Year Month Message
Date                
2017-07-21 07:55:39  Jw  2017   7   hey
2017-07-21 07:55:42  Jw  2017   7   bye bye
2017-07-21 07:55:48  Jw  2017   7   hi hi
2017-07-21 12:29:38  Jw  2017   7   Photo
2017-07-21 12:29:45  Jw  2017   7   abc
```

I grouped it by `Year` and `Month` and aggregate it by `count`:

```
df[df['User']=='Jw'].groupby(['Year', 'Month']).agg({'Message':'count'})
```

result :

```
              Message
Year    Month   
2017    7       193
        8       282
        9       86
        10      245
        11      42
        12      200
2018    1       302
        2       175
        3       65
```

Let's call final grouped dataframe  as `grouped_df`.

What I want to do is plot the `gourped_df`, which has `Year-Month` as `x-axis` and `Message` count as `y-axis`

I think that there are two ways for implementing this:

1. Draw plot directly (I don't know how to but I believe it exists)
2. Remove `Multiindex` and make `Date` column which consists of `Year-Month` and filter out by `grouped_df[['Date', 'Message']]` and plot it. But since this dataframe is multiindex strucutre, I have no idea how to merge these two index as one date column.

Want to know both method or nicer one if exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way for fixing your output

```
df.index=df.index.map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format) 
df
Out[157]: 
         Message
2017-7       193
2017-8       282
2017-9        86
2017-10      245
2017-11       42
2017-12      200
2018-1       302
2018-2       175
2018-3        65
df.plot()
```

[image]

Or we just start from original df

```
df.assign(key=df.Year.astype(str)+'-'df.Month.astype(str))[df['User']=='Jw'].groupby('key').agg({'Message':'count'})
```